# Deploy Flask App on Azure without having output.tar.gz

Tags: azure, flask, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

Recently, I observed changes in the way my Flask App is getting deployed to Azure app service. Earlier I could see all the files under the "Files" folder in Azure Extension in VSCode. Also I could access those files using FTP too. However now I see only "output.tar.gz" file along with some other files.

[image]

Issue is that now I cannot replace individual file when deploying a fix. Also my application generates few file like "log files and CSV files, etc" at runtime which are also not accessible.
My old deployment used to look like below
[image]

Am I missing anything here? I haven't made any change in App Service configuration.

Can someone suggest a solution how to deploy Flask Application on Azure with still having access to individual files deployed or generated at runtime.

Comment: You found anything on this? I am also having the same issue, I think as it is in .gz file, so I am not able to access the app on the generated URL by azure. What do you think?

Comment: @DebjyotiBanerjee, I couldn't find the solution. So i started creating files on blob storage and start creating logs on table storage. At least I get access to files and logs now.